# jQuery - delayed display with loading gif

Tags: jquery

I posted a question yesterday on getting this to work. Today, I got it to work and need some help to tweak it. :)

I've built an interactive lab exercise where a user clicks on the question to retrieve the answer. I've modified it so that there is a delay before the answer appears. For testing, it's set to 1s, I will increase that for production.

Currently, when you click an li element, I'm inserting a loading gif using .after(), then hiding it (and showing the next div) on a delay. It's a little janky code-wise, but the main problem is that if you click on the li element again before the loading completes, it just adds another gif and then screws the whole thing up.

How can I fix that? Test to see if the image has already been inserted and do nothing if so, or something to that effect?

Sandbox: http://sed.freeshell.org/labtest.html

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" content="text/css" href="cssnew.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".step").next().hide();
  $("li").click(function(){
      $(".answer").hide(); //hide all answers on the page
      $(this).next().delay(1000).slideDown(); //display answer after 1s
      $(this).after('<img src="/ajax-loader.gif" />'); //insert loading gif
      $(this).next().delay(1000).hide(0); //after inserting the gif, this.next now refers to the gif, hide it after 1s
      $("li").show(); //in case there were nested li elements, show them
    });
  $("h1").click(function(){
      $(".answer").show();
    });
});
</script>

<style>
body {
background: #fff8f0;
font-family: "Helvetica","Arial","sans-serif";
font-size: 1em;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 { font-family: "Trebuchet MS","Verdana","Helvetica","sans-serif"; margin:0}
h4 { color: #999; margin-top: 10px;}
hr { border: 1px solid #999; }
code { font-weight: bold; font-family: "PT Mono","Consolas","Lucida Console","Courier New","Courier","monospace"; font-size: 1.1em; }
.answer {
display: inline-block;
background: #333;
color: #999;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 5px 20px;
font-family: "PT Mono","Consolas","Lucida Console","Courier New","Courier","monospace";
font-size: 1.1em;
}
.key {color: #0a0}
.var {color: #c6c}
.cmd {color: #eee}
.cmt {color: #0aa}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<ol>
<li class="step">Use the <code>cp</code> command to copy file1 to file2.</li>
<div class="answer">
$ <span class="cmd">cp file1 file2</span>
</div>
</ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps out a bit!

Rather than appending with jQuery to the end we can already have what we need in the HTML and just show and hide it when we need to.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/press/6L64h4ss/)**

```js
$('.question').click(function() {
    
    $(this).next('.answer-container').slideDown().children('.loading').delay(1500).fadeOut(function() {
       $(this).siblings('.answer').fadeIn();
    });
    
});
```

```css
.list-unstyled {
  list-style-type: none;  
}
.answer {
   display: none; 
}
.loading {
    display: block;
    width: 220px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url('http://sed.freeshell.org/ajax-loader.gif');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="questions list-unstyled">
    <li class="question">Question 1</li>
    <li class="answer-container" style="display: none;">
        <div class="loading"></div>
        <span class="answer">Answer: Whoop</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. Unfortunately, I've got a lot of files like this that will need to be edited, but vim macros should knock it out in no time!

Answer (score 1):

I would add a class or an id to your image that you are loading, and check to make sure the image isn't visible before you load it.

**Add a class called loader:**

```
 $(this).after('<img class="loader" src="/ajax-loader.gif" />'); //insert loading gif
```

**Verify the element is not visible before loading:**

```
  if($('.loader').is(':visible') == false){
  [your image loading 
   }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahcjdsxp/)